# vscode Smarty Template Support plugin

Tags: visual-studio-code

May I ask how to make the Smarty Template Support plugin of vscode support the .dwt format, now he only supports the code highlighting and prompts of .tpl
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrWIK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQKoA.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the setting: **Files: Associations** (`"files.associations"`)

add the entry:

```
"*.dwt" : "smarty"
```